# Questions about the $K$-theory of the algebraic standard Podleś sphere

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, kt.k-theory-and-homology, algebraic-k-theory, noncommutative-geometry

Given $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ irrational, the $K$-theory of the smooth noncommutative $2$-torus $C^\infty_\theta(\mathbb{T}^2)$ is well understood in relation to that of the corresponding $\mathrm{C}^\ast$-algebraic noncommutative $2$-torus $C_\theta(\mathbb{T}^2)$:

1. the inclusion $C^\infty_\theta(\mathbb{T}^2) \hookrightarrow C_\theta(\mathbb{T}^2)$ induces an isomorphism $K_0(C^\infty_\theta(\mathbb{T}^2)) \to K_0(C_\theta(\mathbb{T}^2))$;
2. the $K_0$-monoid $\mathcal{V}(C^\infty_\theta(\mathbb{T}^2))$ is cancellative (just like $\mathcal{V}(C_\theta(\mathbb{T}^2))$;
3. the “good” Fréchet pre-$\mathrm{C}^\ast$-algebra $C^\infty_\theta(\mathbb{T}^2)$ has stable rank one (just like $C_\theta(\mathbb{T}^2)$).

In particular, by standard lore, fact 3. implies fact 2.

Now, let $q \in (0,1)$ be given, let $\mathcal{O}_q(\mathbb{CP}^1)$ denote the corresponding algebraic standard Podleś sphere, and let $C_q(\mathbb{CP}^1)$ denote its $C^\ast$-algebraic completion—I'd like to know to what extent the above picture is known to apply, *mutatis mutandis*, in this case. Note that $\mathcal{O}_q(\mathbb{CP}^1)$ is not closed under the holomorphic functional calculus in $C_q(\mathbb{CP}^1)$, so that the usual results (which are applicable to smooth noncommutative $2$-tori) do not apply here.

1. Calculations of [Masuda–Nakagami–Watanabe](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01254546) and [Hajac–Majid](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9803003) combine to imply that the inclusion $\iota: \mathcal{O}_q(\mathbb{CP}^1) \hookrightarrow C_q(\mathbb{CP}^1)$ induces a surjection $K_0(\iota) : K_0(\mathcal{O}_q(\mathbb{CP}^1)) \to K_0(C_q(\mathbb{CP}^2))$. **Is $K_0(\iota)$ known to be injective?** Bijectivity of $K_0(\iota)$ is folkloric and may well be somehow obvious given surjectivity, but it isn't obvious to me, and I've struggled to find an explicit reference for injectivity or come up with my own argument.
2. It is a result of [Bach](https://www.proquest.com/docview/305317896?pq-origsite=gscholar&fromopenview=true) that $\mathcal{V}(C_q(\mathbb{CP}^1))$ is cancellative. **Is $\mathcal{V}(\mathcal{O}_q(\mathbb{CP}^1))$ known to be cancellative, or is this an open question?**
3. It is another result of Bach that $C_q(\mathbb{CP}^1)$ has stable rank $1$. **Is anything known about the Bass stable rank of $\mathcal{O}_q(\mathbb{CP}^1)$?**

I've done my best to trawl the literature on all three points, but I've hit a wall. I'd be grateful for any pointers, even just machinery that could be applicable in this case.